# PHP-phantomjs, avoid page break

Tags: php-phantomjs

I am using the PHP-phantomjs and follow the doc I can output pdf and img. http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

but I have problem with page break. when a charts in the end of the page,but overflowed, it will be split in another page,like the capture below:
[image: Page capture]

I found some advice:

```
<div id="main" style="page-break-inside: avoid;"></div>
```

But it doesn't work, or maybe I get it wrong. 
And if it is the solution, that means I have to write this in every element of html? Sounds not good.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found some solutions on [github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13524). As I understand PhantomJS has bug whith scales the page. Try to add to body:

```
body { zoom : 0.75 }
```

Comment: doesn't work either... (zoom works, but page break no)

Comment: @LucLaverdure Did you see the other answers on my link? https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13524